# Issues with operator associativity in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, notation, education

Textbook authors often point put that operators aren't in general commutative which is a source of confusion. Another point of confusion, which I haven't seen mentioned anywhere is the issue with associativity.

One might naively perform a calculation like $$\hat{p}\hat{x}\psi(x)=-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}x\psi(x)=-i\hbar\frac{dx}{dx}\psi(x)=-i\hbar\psi(x).$$ Which is what I did when I was first trying to evaluate this. Because I didn't know operators don't associate like this. No textbook that I know of mentions it and I am probably not the only one who fell into this pitfall.

I am looking for more information about issues concerning operator associativity in QM.

EDIT: Consider a case like this: $\hat{A}\hat{p}\hat{x}$.

Comment: Since you only have two operators, and associativity is the property $(AB)C = A(BC)$, it cannot possibly be the issue here.

Comment: As Ricky implicitly points out in their answer, the issue is that you didn't use the chain rule when applying the derivative. The derivative should be applied to $x\psi(x)$, not just $x$.

Comment: A number of comments removed. A person who wanted to discuss grammar might make a post on [meta], but they would want to do their research first.

Comment: A number of further comments removed. A person making a post on [meta] would also want to make sure their post was consistent with the [code of conduct](/conduct). Knock it off, here.

Comment: There is only one way that $\hat{p}\hat{x}\psi$ should be read, and that is as $\hat{p}(\hat{x}\psi)$. Likewise, $(\hat{A}\hat{p}\hat{x})$ would be an operator that maps $\psi$ to $\hat{A}[\hat{p}(\hat{x}\psi)]$.

Answer (score 10):

QM operators are associative, but you do have to be careful about how you calculate things. $\hat p$ and $\hat x$ are linear maps from functions to functions. $\hat p$ maps the function $f(x)$ to $-i\hbar f'(x)$ while $\hat x$ maps a function $f(x)$ to $xf(x)$. To multiply them is equivalent to composing the linear maps. Here's how to compute $\hat p \hat x$:

To exactly know what the final operator is, we need to know it's behaviour when applied to all functions $f$. So let $f$ be an arbitrary function. Then we have:

$$
\hat p\hat x f(x) = \hat p (\hat x f(x)) = \hat p (xf(x)) = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(xf(x)) = -i\hbar(f(x) + xf'(x))
$$

Now that we know the behaviour when applied to all functions, we can remove the unknown function $f$ and just write the operator as:

$$
\hat p \hat x = -i\hbar(1 + x\frac{\partial}{\partial x})
$$

I think Griffiths has some discussion of this "dummy function" technique for multiplying operators.